# How to fix error messages like "argument list for class template is missing"?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Ok, I tried looking for other solutions related to mine, but I could not find the solution. I am using Visual Studio 2017, I was watching tutorial and he was using linux, but also this code is from a book. My problem is that I am getting an error message on the following:

> "argument list for class template "std::iterator" is missing"
>
> " success cannot deduce 'auto' type (initializer required)"
>
> "identifier "key" is undefined"
>
> "identifier "b" is undefined expected a ']'
>
> " count cannot deduce 'auto' type (initializer required)"

Here is a part of my code:

```
list<billionaire> billionaires{
{"Bill Gates", 86.0, "USA"},
{"Warren Buffet", 75.6, "USA"},
{"Jeff Bezos", 72.8, "USA"},
};

std::map<std::string, std::pair<const billionaire, std::size_t>> m;

for (const auto &b : billionaires) {
    auto[iterator, success] = m.try_emplace(b.country, b, 1); //iterator and success are underlined red

    if (!success) {
        iterator->second.second += 1;
    }
}

for (const auto &[key, value] : m) { // key underlined red
    const auto &[b, count] = value; //b and count underlined red

    cout << b.country << " : " << count << " billionaires. Richest is "
        << b.name << " with " << b.dollars << " B$\n";
}
```

Comment: You're sure you're compiling in C++17 mode? And this code is inside a function body?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Visual Studio 2017, it should already have C++17 enabled, shouldn't? Is there a way to verify? And yes inside function body, seems like c++17 library is not functioning properly.

Comment: @AlexH - To verify, you can print the value of `__cplusplus` macro (by example: `std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;`. If prints the value `201703`, you're compiling C++17.

Comment: @AlexH: "*it should already have C++17 enabled, shouldn't?*" No, that's not how it works (anymore). Like all other C++ compilers, VS requires you to use a version switch to pick which version of C++ to compile for. Otherwise, it defaults to C++14.

Comment: It printed 199711 and now I know I don't have C++17 enabled, so how do I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by right clicking on project name and then went to Properties > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard > and selected "ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard (/std:c++latest)". Seems like some settings changed when updated.